# How to install Python dependency properly? (maybe without sudo?)

Tags: python, pip, sudo

I'm trying to run some code with python. It is using [tweepy](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. Then, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy
ImportError: No module named 'tweepy'
```

So, I tried to install dependency:
`pip install tweepy`
And it get permission denied:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sockshandler.py'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Next thing to do is to run using `sudo`. I had a bad experience by using `sudo` for docker, because it creates protected files all over my local. But I finally tried it anyway `sudo pip install tweepy`
It returns success, but I still get the same error when I tried to run `python3 myscript.py`

But, I see some warning to upgrade the pip, so I think maybe that's it. I tried to upgrade pip using both `pip install --upgrade pip` and `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

Still not working.. I tried one last trick up my sleeve. Change the terminal. I think, "maybe after installing, some environment variable not running on this terminal"

Nope. Not working. I admit it should be a newbie question. Having tried some solution on the web, but still not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use python3, you should be using pip3, pip is most likely the python2 pip.

However, better is using `python3 -m pip install tweepy` that ensures you use the pip for your specific python version.

You can also install it as a user without sudo for just your local account:
`python3 -m pip install --user tweepy`

Comment: An additional advice to complete this accurate answer: you could use a virtual environment (using `python3 -m venv <path>`) to simplify pip install calls and restrict them to the scope of a given project (when the venv is activated, you can safely use `pip install`, which will call the right pip and make the installation contextual to the venv).

Comment: I'm trying to use `python3 -m pip install --user tweepy` but getting this error `/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip`

Comment: owh, I think I should install pip3 first using `sudo apt install python3-pip`. And now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message:

```
... Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7 ....
```

You installed tweepy in your python2 Installation. 
Use `pip3 install tweepy` instead. Maybe with sudo when you get the error with permission denied again. After that you can go with

`python3 myscript.py`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--user` flag, like so...

```
pip|pip3 install <PACKAGE> --user
```

This will install it in a location available and writeable to your user

See https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-to-the-user-site

Answer (score 0):

You seems to have 2 python installations on the machine. Python 3.x and Python 2.7.
When you run the `pip` command , the alias points to `pip2` which installs packages for Python 2.7 - which is clear in your error message

```
Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sockshandler.py'
```

So if you want to install packages for python 3, then use the command `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Like `sudo pip3 install tweepy`

If you want the `pip` to work as `pip3` you can consider adding an alias with `alias pip=pip3`

You have to make sure the pip is pointing to right python version.